# No Error but Empty output file.

Tags: python

I have following program which reads two text files(hw.txt and quiz.txt) which contains name of students and scores of their hw and quiz such as:

**hw.txt**

John 100

David 100

John 50

John 75

Ellen 12

David 23

Helen 60

**quiz.txt**

John 50

David 70

john 25

Ellen 100

Helen 100

and after reading two files, the below program should combine the data into one single text file(scores.txt).  The program runs without any errors but the output text file(scores.txt) contains nothing o.O? Been digging stack-overflow Reddit everywhere but found no solution.

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.hw = 0
        self.quiz = 0

def init_Student(names,student_list):
    i = 1
    for j in names:
        student_list.append(Student(i,j))
        i += 1

def find_student(student_list,name):
    for x in student_list:
        if x.name == name:
            return x.id
    return 0

def get_HW_Scores(file_name, student_list):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            i = find_student(student_list, line.split(" ")[0])
            if i != 0:
                student_list[i].hw += int(line.split(" ")[1])

def get_Quiz_Scores(file_name, student_list):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            i = find_student(student_list, line.split(" ")[0])
            if i != 0:
                student_list[i].quiz += int(line.split(" ")[1])

def assign_grade(score):
    if score >=97:
        return "A+"
    elif score >=93:
        return "A"
    elif score >=90:
        return "A-"
    elif score >=87:
        return "B+"
    elif score >=83:
        return "B"
    elif score >=80:
        return "B-"
    elif score >=77:
        return "C+"
    elif score >=73:
        return "C"
    elif score >=70:
        return "C-"
    elif score >=67:
        return "D+"
    elif score >=63:
        return "D"
    elif score >=60:
        return "D-"
    elif score <60:
        return "F"


def output_Scores(student_list):
    f = open("scores.txt", 'w')
    for x in student_list:
        f.write(x.name + "\n")
        f.write("HW_Percent: " + str(x.hw/3) + "% \n")
        f.write("Quiz_Percent: " + str(x.quiz/3) + "% \n")
        num = (x.hw/3)*0.5 + (x.quiz/3)*0.5
        f.write("Overall: " + str(num) + "%" "(" + assign_grade(num) + ")" + "\n")
    f.close


def main():
    names = []
    student_list = []
    init_Student(names, student_list)
    get_HW_Scores("hw.txt", student_list)
    get_Quiz_Scores("quiz.txt", student_list)
    output_Scores(student_list)
main()
```

Comment: Add parenthesis after `f.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill student names to `names` variable in `main` function.

In addition, `i` variable in `init_Student` function should be initialized to 0 because first index in array is 0.

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self,id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.hw = 0
        self.quiz = 0

def init_Student(names,student_list):
    i = 0  # Initialize to 0 for index access
    for j in names:
        student_list.append(Student(i,j))
        i += 1

def find_student(student_list,name):
    for x in student_list:
        if x.name == name:
            return x.id
    return 0

def get_HW_Scores(file_name, student_list):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            i = find_student(student_list, line.split(" ")[0])
            if i != 0:
                student_list[i].hw += int(line.split(" ")[1])

def get_Quiz_Scores(file_name, student_list):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            i = find_student(student_list, line.split(" ")[0])
            if i != 0:
                student_list[i].quiz += int(line.split(" ")[1])

def assign_grade(score):
    if score >=97:
        return "A+"
    elif score >=93:
        return "A"
    elif score >=90:
        return "A-"
    elif score >=87:
        return "B+"
    elif score >=83:
        return "B"
    elif score >=80:
        return "B-"
    elif score >=77:
        return "C+"
    elif score >=73:
        return "C"
    elif score >=70:
        return "C-"
    elif score >=67:
        return "D+"
    elif score >=63:
        return "D"
    elif score >=60:
        return "D-"
    elif score <60:
        return "F"


def output_Scores(student_list):
    f = open("scores.txt", 'w')
    for x in student_list:
        f.write(x.name + "\n")
        f.write("HW_Percent: " + str(x.hw/3) + "% \n")
        f.write("Quiz_Percent: " + str(x.quiz/3) + "% \n")
        num = (x.hw/3)*0.5 + (x.quiz/3)*0.5
        f.write("Overall: " + str(num) + "%" "(" + assign_grade(num) + ")" + "\n")
    f.close

def main():
    names = ['John', 'David']  # Fill student names
    student_list = []
    init_Student(names, student_list)
    get_HW_Scores("hw.txt", student_list)
    get_Quiz_Scores("quiz.txt", student_list)
    print(student_list)
    output_Scores(student_list)

main()
```

The result.

```
$ cat scores.txt
John
HW_Percent: 0%
Quiz_Percent: 0%
Overall: 0.0%(F)
David
HW_Percent: 64%
Quiz_Percent: 64%
Overall: 64.0%(D)
```

Comment: Man. python is too hard to understand :( Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hi @David, I am glad to be of service to you. If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: 0 does not appear to be a valid id for a Student; find_student reserves 0 as a "not found" signal.